Why are criminals not worried about the hostages seeing their faces?
In the Spanish series La Casa de Papel dubbed internationally as Money Heist the robbers decide to set 11 hostages free. The robbers rarely wear masks in front of the hostages. They always wear them outside the mint when they are facing the police troops.
For the release they decide they should speak to the press in a televised program. First, Nairobi tells the rest of the gang that she will speak to them wearing a mask. But then Berlin tells her he will do it. Because he is a well-known criminal and it's not a problem for him to not wear a mask in front of them. Nairobi agrees and Berlin speak to the press and releases the hostages.
Two questions here:

While the robbers are so afraid their faces are revealed to the public and the police, they decide to set 11 hostages free. All of them have seen the gang members' faces. Why were they ignorant that the released hostages will help the police to sketch their faces? Why did they set them free while they knew it would be another trouble for them?
Why didn't the police ask the released hostages to help them sketch the robbers' faces?


Thank you for your edit @Paulie_D ; but the criminals not being worried about the hostages seeing their faces is explainable (at least before their decision to set some of them free). But after that decision it's pretty odd that they still aren't worried. Also, the decision itself was odd. Why did they decide to set some of the hostages free while they had seen their faces?

Out of universe: so we can see their faces during more of the show.  In universe: A photo of you (because you go outside and are seen by the authorities) can be used to identify who you are if you already have a record,  a hostage can only describe you, or identify you once you've already been caught.  A photofit of you is never as good as a photograph.

@iandotkelly - 11 photofits are going to come up with 11 entirely different-looking pictures... :-)

@Valorum Why different photofits? The 11 hostages can come up with a single photofit for each robber

@EtackSxchange - e-fits work best when there is one (or at most two) people who have seen the criminal. When you have multiple people doing multiple photofits, you end up with multiple images that look quite dissimilar. It actually introduces reasonable doubt into the minds of juries, so detectives are dissuaded from doing so.

@EtackSxchange: It doesn't matter if every hostage is interviewed separately or all together. Fact of the matter is, you will end up with 11 wildly different descriptions. Study after study shows that more often than not, eyewitnesses cannot even agree on things like ethnicity, skin color, hair color, height, build, whether the person has a beard or not, tattoos, etc. The only difference when interviewing them all together is that the biggest bully in the group will convince the others that their description is the only correct one.

@Valorum Well, all the robbers in the series had had records in the past. So the police could easily show the photographs of several recorded criminals to the released hostages. But they didn't do it! Also, in the photofit case, it's not 50 years ago where the police sketched the descriptions by hand! Today, they use computer softwares that contain several real facial features of recorded criminals. You can choose an eye, a nose, etc to build a complete face. Even sketched facial features aren't used anymore in softwares for the reasons you mentioned.

@EtackSxchange: You are making a whole bunch of assumptions on how easy it is to match a witness' memory to either an incredibly accurate photofit, or find an actual mugshot. There are lots of criminal records, not everyone still looks the same from when they were last arrested, and the more photos you look at the more you forget the face you were trying to remember. If it were as easy as you're thinking it is, we would be identifying way more criminals on sight alone.

@Flater But the police could at least try it by showing actual mugshots to the released hostages. It could help (even if we consider failing as a probability). It didn't have any costs or any harms.

@EtackSxchange: TIme is not infinite. Time spent doing one thing leads to time not spent doing another thing. The reality of it is that the cost-benefit ratio of things that are unlikely to come up with results is simply too high. Thinking that police do anything humanly possible to solve a case is naive. That's not a dig at the police's standards, that's just a very real fact of life that everyone has to deal with (including the police).
